# How do I get a previous date from iterrows() function (Python and Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'm going through as follows:

```
  for index, row in my_dataframe.iterrows():
        cursor.execute(""" UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COLUMN1 = %s, 
        COLUMN2 = %s WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_COLUMN, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = %s AND COLUMN1 IS NULL""",
                                        (row['VALUE_A'],
                                         row['VALUE_B'],
                                         row['DATE_C']
                                         ))
```

What I need is to apply something like:

```
row['DATE_C'] -1 day.
```

How can I do that? How can we do row manipulations in python / pandas data frame.

Now, I know if we took out the row['...'] syntax and this was basic sql, we could just use the - interval '1' day syntax to get this done. But I need to use this loop to achieve my goal.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

```py
pd.to_datetime(row['DATE_C']) - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```